# Remote control to spectrum analyzer

Tags: python

I want to read a waveform from the spectrum analyzer. Here is my code:

```
import visa
import time  


rm = visa.ResourceManager()

inst = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::172.16.34.10::10001::SOCKET')
print(inst)
time.sleep(10)
inst.write("*IDN?")
b=inst.read()
print(b)
inst.close()
```

It gives me an error:

> VI_ERROR_IO (-1073807298): Could not perform operation because of I/O error.

I managed to make a connection using matlab with the same IP address and port.

Does anybody know what would cause this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `visa`, but a google-search of that error points to some possibly helpful resources: https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa/issues/174, or https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/I-Get-quot-VISA-Hex-0xBFFF003E-Could-not-perform-operation/td-p/476931/page/2

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have solved the problem.